# Does a static function get called in a class automatically whenever I invoke a function?

Tags: java, static

So I have a public class and within this class are several public functions including a static method.

```
public class TestVocabValidator {

    static { getEnumList( vocabList.values() ); }

    public static Iterator<String> getVocabEntries(String x) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Whenever I call on the function `getVocabEntries()`, does the static method get called automatically?

Comment: You stated in a comment to Mena's answer that your SQL code fails if the static initializer isn't called. What does `getEnumList( vocabList.values() )` do? Why is it `TestVocabValidator`'s job to initialize something unrelated to `TestVocabValidator`?

Answer (score 3):

The static blocks (e.g. `static {...}`) are executed once, when the class' name is referenced and the class is loaded.

The static methods (e.g. `getVocabEntries`) are executed every time they are invoked.

Comment: So if I call the getVocabEntries function, the static function DOES get initialized, right?

Comment: I think there's a slight confusion in vocabulary. In Java, "function" is more or less synonymous to "methods" (Java 8 enthusiasts may now declare me Enemy Of The People). What I suspect you are referencing by "function" is a static block. As mentioned, it's executed only once, when the class is loaded.

Comment: @user3851283 The first part is not a static *function*, it is a static *initializer*, and it will be called when the class is first loaded, even if `getVocabEntries` isn't called.

Comment: Yes, what Andreas says. Also in this case, if `getEnumList`  is `static` and variable `vocabList` is `static` and declared before your `static` block (else it wouldn't compile), `getEnumList` will be invoked on `vocabList` once when the class is loaded.

Comment: @Andreas So in the file that I'm currently writing, how can I make sure that this static initializer gets invoked if I don't call the 'getVocabEntries' function?

Comment: @user3851283 It gets invoked when the class is first *loaded*, which occurs the first time it's *used*, either statically as `MyClass.myField` or `MyClass.myMethod()`, or when creating a new instance `new MyClass()`, or if you do things like that on a *subclass* of `MyClass`. It may or may not happen if referenced using `instanceof` (on Java 8 it doesn't).

Comment: @Andreas also through the reflective `Class.forName` idiom, just to add to the list.

Comment: @Andreas So in this case how would I write it as? TestVocabValidator.<what>

Comment: @user3851283 Correct, but if you don't use the `TestVocabValidator.class` value, the compiler *might* remove the code.

Comment: @Andreas Rightnow I'm trying to get the SQL to read the vocab list and the static initializer has to be invoked, but it's not being implemented unless I call the `TestVocabInitializer.getVocabEntries(x)`. If I take it out, then I get an error. So I can't just put `TestVocabValidator.class` becuase it would give an error. How can I correct this?

Comment: @user3851283 Your `TestVocabValidator` static initializer is initializing data *external* to `TestVocabValidator`? Bad logic right there.

Comment: @Andreas So should I just call the `getVocabEntries` function directly instead?

Comment: Sorry, Mena, we hijacked your answers comment section. Continuing in question comments...

Comment: @Andreas haha tha's allright. Was wondering where this would go :)

Answer (score 1):

Not whenever you call that static method. The first time that class is loaded, in this case the first time you call that method, the static block is called.